# google adverts no longer displaying?

Tags: javascript, adsense

This is a bit weird - i have goodle ads on my site with Google maps v3.

However on this page they do not show up... 
http://www.haroldstreet.org.uk/munros/ 
(They should be in the blank spaces in the right column and one at the very bottom of the page.)

But they do often show up after the URL of the same page's url is extended by adding "?somemadeuptag=x" to the end of it. (even though the URL tag is not used by the page)

A similar page based on the same underlying dynamic code
http://www.haroldstreet.org.uk/wainwrights/
has no such issues.

Hi Me again - i've now systematically cut out all non-relevant code to give the following much simplified page (no other JS, no google maps, and no CSS structure)...
http://www.haroldstreet.org.uk/test/
For me at least this shows the same behaviour - the google ads should be a banner top and bottom & show grey if they fail.

It seems to happen to me, irrespective of browser
Any ideas on why this might be happening?

---

ADDED LATER:

OK i've still got the problem but i've added alternative ads so it's not so obvious on the http://www.haroldstreet.org.uk/munros/ page - which now shows amozon adverts instead.

The simplified page content is still on this TEST page and it still doesn't show the appropriate adverts - in the two empty grey banners top and bottom.... 
http://www.haroldstreet.org.uk/test/

I still can't see what is wrong - could google have banned the names of Scottish mountains????

Comment: The only ad is for a The Munros book in the top right, correct? I see it in all the pages.

Comment: Oops, I have AdBlock Plus running. That's why I don't see them anywhere!

Comment: When I turn off ABP for your site, I see all the ads on both versions.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.haroldstreet.org.uk/test/ to see the issue on a really simple page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've not actually solved the problem - it is still evident on this simplified page for anyone who is interested...
http://www.haroldstreet.org.uk/test

But the following might be useful work-round to someone...

First i upgraded my ad code to the lastest version and set it up to show alternate ads (from amazon in this case). This was a useful alternative to just having empty ad spaces - see this example...
http://www.haroldstreet.org.uk/waypoints/download/?list=humps

Then for my more important /munros/ page - i've added the following line to the google ad code.

```
   google_page_url = "http://www.haroldstreet.org.uk/waypoints/download/?list=munros&area=04";
```

This seems to prompt google back into giving closely related ads, and restores the Google adds to my /Munros/ page.

So its not a fix, but a reasonable work-round

Ta
phil

Comment: Thw whole problem solved itself later on - i presume google fixed something at their end!